I need Nigeria state shape file
I need Nigeria state shape file
I am looking for shape files(polygons data) of all the districts in the world. I can find few files from different sources for districts of one country but I need one (updated) file that have all the districts in the world OR one reliable source from where I can get files may be ...

You can access shape file of Nigeria which also includes boundaries of administrative regions within Nigeria, under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0. Access here.
Also more detailed shape file is available on openAfrica, which also includes communities and local areas. Access here.
